# Is there an equivalent of getch in sfml?

Tags: c++, sfml

Currently I am trying to create a function that behaves like `getch()` (pauses until a key is it) only using the sfml libary. It is important to note that this is expected to be called outside of the event loop. I've tried searching around for anything akin for it and I haven't found anything. My current code for it looks like this:

```
int waitForKeyboardHit (sf::Window *win) {
    sf::Event event;
    while (true) {
        while (win->pollEvent (event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                return event.key.code;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

while that works fine for the most part, however if any KeyPressed events go on the event window queue prior to this function being called instead of the function immediately ends instead of waiting until the next keyboard press. I've tried looking for ways to clear the window's event queue before calling this function but I haven't found anything that can do that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while (win->pollEvent(event)) ;` (mind the semicolon) will clear the event queue, but that's probably not how you want to do it: stalling the whole program and its logic for input is rarely a good thing. Using some kind of [FSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) would be better, I believe. Like this example from Wikipedia where the machine waits for a coin (like you wait for a key press): [image]

Besides, you should redraw your scene and call `display()` in your `while(true)` loop to refresh the screen at least from time to time.